# Determine the type of encryption used

Tags: encryption, cryptography, php

I am trying to determine the type of encryption used for a site whose password is stored in the database. The site is built using the fuelphp. It has the password of the form (B65qdjYiMWzizMol7BmG4knKh4OAu9033kSAPcCK5Cs=) which encryption is this?

Comment: Asking the site to break encryption for you is out of scope.  However, you can use CyberChef to figure out a bit about it.  From there, you can work on it yourself.  Here's what I used:
https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64(%27A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D%27,true)Entropy(%27Shannon%20scale%27)&input=QjY1cWRqWWlNV3ppek1vbDdCbUc0a25LaDRPQXU5MDMza1NBUGNDSzVDcz0

Comment: In this specific case this looks like a base64 encoded. Decoding it results in a 32 byte (256 bit) binary which for example could be SHA-256. Of course it could also be anything else with SHA-256 as the last round, SHA-512  cut to 256 bit, two different MD5 concatenated, ...